# H1 followed by H2 without text among the titles afflicts the SEO?

Tags: seo, h1, title

Is it a correct way if I write a H1 without **any** text under and then immediately after I write the H2?

The H2 will be instead followed by the text of my page. To be clearest as possible the structure could be this:

```
<h1>Camping in Australia: a great choice in the untainted nature!<h1/>
<h2>Campgrounds for tents for your camping in Australia</h2>
<p>some paragraph</p>
```

As you can see, the h1 title has not text, and it's immediately followed by the h2 title wich will, instead, contain important informations in the text for the user.

Comment: This is a classic case of over thinking things.

Comment: Thank you @JohnConde So... Do you think that SEO would not be afflicted by this practice? Would you use H1 e H2 this way?

Comment: I would, I have, and millions of others site do as well.

Comment: I don't think the OP was overthinking things, I had the same question. If you are attempting a top 10 rank of a landing page for a highly competitive keyword, every part of your SEO counts. I changed the order of keywords in a title and bumped up 2 spots in the top 10, it isn't unreasonable to ask if its better to have text between an H1 and H2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These h1-h4 headings represent the logical heading structure which means there is nothing wrong, You can have a main heading and it can immediately follow it with subheading to categorize your sections in the body.

However in order to be logical the subheading should be niche of the main heading rather than talking about a completely different topic.